# Filling in the missing field using SQL

Tags: sql, database

This is actually related to the question I asked previously: [Filling in the missing field for column in data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43955772/filling-in-the-missing-field-for-column-in-data-frame-in-r)

I have the following columns:

```
casenum  boxtype         numballs
  1         A               10
  1         B               20
  2         B               1
  2         C               2
  2         D               12
  3         A               10
  3         B               20
  3         C               1
  3         D               2
  .         .               .
  .         .               .
  .         .               .
```

I want to have it in a format

```
casenum         A                 B              C                  D
  1            10                20              0                  0
  2            0                  1              2                 12
  3            10                20              1                  2
  .            .                  .              .                  .
  .            .                  .              .                  .
```

I have learned how to do so in R.

Then I was wondering if I could do the similar thing in SQL.

It looks like the query should end with "group by casenum, boxtype," but then I wasn't sure how to make those 4 new columns using SQL.

Is there an easy way of doing it in SQL?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: you can also look into the Pivot function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pivot query.  A general way to solve it uses conditional aggregation:

```
select casenum,
       sum(case when boxtype = 'A' then numballs else 0 end) as A,
       sum(case when boxtype = 'B' then numballs else 0 end) as B,
       sum(case when boxtype = 'C' then numballs else 0 end) as C,
       sum(case when boxtype = 'D' then numballs else 0 end) as D
from t
group by casenum;
```

Comment: Ah got it. so i cannot group by numballs

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server 2005+, then you can use the PIVOT function to transform the data from rows into columns.

If your values(boxtype) are known, then you will hard-code the query:

```
select *
from 
(
  select casenum, boxtype, numballs
  from #table
) src
pivot
(
  sum(numballs)
  for week in ([A], [B], [C],[D])
) piv;
```

if you need to generate the boxtype dynamically, your code will be:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(boxtype) 
                    from table
                    group by boxtype
                    order by boxtype
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT casenum,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select casenum, boxtype, numballs
                from table
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(numballs)
                for boxtype in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```